# Maven dependency version in profile section when defined in dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven

We have several of our project modules defined in our master pom within the `dependencyManagement` section so that they can be used in child poms but maintain a consistent version. This is pretty standard, I think.

Now, within a `profiles` section of a child POM I would like to add a dependency and not define the version as I know this dependency definition exists in the Parent POM `dependencyManagement` section.

e.g.

```
...

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>DEV_PC</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.our.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1</artifactId>            
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
 ...
```

I am seeing some odd behavior in the build and wonder if it this approach is allowed or do you always have to define the version of a dependency in a profile section?

---

To answer my own question:
You can use dependencies that are defined in a `dependencyManagement` section without a version in the `profiles` section as shown above in my example.

I have added a comment below explaining the odd behavior I had seen.

Comment: Can you give an example of odd behavior you noticed in the build?

Comment: First please add the output of your build which shows the behaviour...apart from that defining dependencies in profiles does not really make sense...cause it sounds like you are trying to created artifacts for different environments...

Comment: The "odd" behavior I mentioned was, in my case anyway, the artifact was not being included in the war file the build was making. With some further investigation I managed to discover that the `DepedencyManagement` definition of the module had scope set to test which explains why it didn't get included in the war.